# Is it common for a female to refer to her fellows as "brethren" ?

Tags: word-usage, archaicisms

I know that "brethren" can mean "fellow members", but I have usually heard it used when a man is referring to his fellows or brothers. But can a female do that ? Let's assume I am the sole female in a group of males, can I refer to the other members of the group as "brethren" ?

On a similar note, is the behavior the same with "sistren" as well (I know it is not common as brethren) ? Could I refer to a group of females (when I am a male myself) as my sistren ?

Comment: [**Sistren**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-is-the-female-equivalent-of-brethren) *- had fallen completely out of use by the middle of the 16th century. It has recently been revived, typically by feminist writers, with the new meaning 'fellow women'*. It's not currently listed at all in the full subscription-only OED.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah I read that too, it is said to be used by feminists though.

Comment: Are you a feminist (or supporter thereof)? Assuming it's mere "happenstance" that you're the only female in a group of males (or the only *male* in a group of *females*) it's not necessarily a good idea to call attention to the gender bias, just as you might not wish to use subtle tricks of language to call attention to the fact that one person in a group happens to be of a different race / religion / sexual orientation to all the others. Unless you're being deliberately facetious, I'd avoid it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am neither a feminist nor in a group, I am merely wondering whether that usage would be correct.

Comment: This is an interesting question (+1). Females can call a group of male siblings *brothers*, but it would sound odd to call them her *fellow* brothers because that would assert that she was one of the brothers. I think the word *brethren* tends to come across as *fellow brothers*, rather than just the plain *brothers*.

Comment: I'd say ***brethren*** today is almost always "dated" or "facetious" except in certain religious contexts. It still comes naturally to *some* native speakers, but if you're not already one of those I really think you should steer it a wide berth (you're *very* likely to unknowingly use it inappropriately).

Comment: @Lawrence Nice explanation, I would add it as an answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I really love how it sounds, and I want to use it, which is the main reason I asked this question. You are right though, it is hard to not use it incorrectly.

Comment: @Taurus Done. :)

Comment: Necessary Kliban reference: [Brethren and cistern](http://www.coldbacon.com/pics/kliban/wyp_brethren&cistern.jpg)

Comment: Taurus: Unfortunately, it's somewhat in the nature of language that there's little correlation between what sounds "nice" to speakers of *different* languages (causing incredible headaches for marketeers within international companies who'd like globally consistent product names). And things get *especially* complicated when we're talking about words that have strong religious connotations (even if you're *not* an ardent feminist, you might be a bit bothered by the "men-only" implications of, say, Egypt's *Muslim Brotherhood*).

Comment: Brethren is also common in fraternal orders.

Comment: @Davo: [**Freemasonry**](http://upminsterhall.org.uk/what-is-freemasonry/)  *is a society of men concerned with moral and **spiritual** values [it's a "fraternal order"].* I'm sure there are still plenty of active *college fraternities* in the US, but I doubt they often refer to each other as *brethren*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Females can call a group of male siblings *brothers*, but it would sound odd to call them her *fellow* brothers because that would assert that she was one of the brothers.

I think the word *brethren* tends to come across as *fellow brothers*, rather than just the plain *brothers*.

The definitions below support this 'inclusive' feel:

> **brethren** *plural noun*
>   1 Fellow Christians or members of a male religious order.
>   1.1 (ironic, humorous) People belonging to a particular group.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brethren)